# Excel VBA code is clearing Pivot Table Filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter

Can someone please review my code and tell me what is causing it clear the filters on my pivot tables before converting them to text?

For reference, this code takes a 20 sheet workbook, converts all the workbooks to text only, deletes a few worksheets, makes some readability changes and then saves the workbook as a new file for distribution. For some reason, the output clears the pivot table filters on the last 2 sheets of the workbook. Everything else works as expected. Any help is appreciated. I pieced this together from the internet and my own limited VBA skills so please feel free to offer any other pointers as well. Thanks in advance.

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Dim xAF As AutoFilter
    Dim xFs As Filters
    Dim xLos As ListObjects
    Dim xLo As ListObject
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xIntC, xF1, xF2, xCount As Integer
    Dim filedate As String
    Dim fileyear As String
    Dim filemonth As String
    Dim fHome As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xWs In Application.Worksheets
        xWs.ShowAllData
        Set xLos = xWs.ListObjects
        xCount = xLos.Count
        For xF1 = 1 To xCount
         Set xLo = xLos.Item(xF1)
         Set xRg = xLo.Range
         xIntC = xRg.Columns.Count
         For xF2 = 1 To xIntC
            xLo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=xF2
         Next
        Next
    Next
 
    
'Copy all worksheets as text only
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wsh.Cells.Copy
        wsh.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
       
    'declare variable to hold Variant containing array whose elements are the index numbers or names of the sheets you want to delete
    Dim mySheetNames() As Variant
 
    'specify (using index numbers or names) the sheets you want to delete
    mySheetNames = Array("Data", "Instructions Page")
 
    'suppress the dialog box that asks the user to confirm the sheet deletion
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
    'identify sheets you want to delete, and delete them
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheetNames).Delete
 

    
    'Return all sheets to cell A1
    For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    wsh.Activate
    wsh.[a1].Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    wsh.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1, ColumnLevels:=1
    Next wsh
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Month(Now()) = 1 Then
    filemonth = 12
Else
    filemonth = Format(Month(Now()) - 1, "00")
End If

If Month(Now()) = 1 Then
    fileyear = Right(Year(Now()) - 1, 2)
Else
    fileyear = Right(Year(Now), 2)
End If

filedate = fileyear & filemonth
fHome = "T:\Actuary\Metrics\NB\New Business Quality\Close Ratio & Quality v." & filedate & ".xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fHome, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    're-enable the display of alerts and messages
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
MsgBox ("Close Ratio & Quality v." & filedate & ".xlsx created successfully")
```

Comment: Avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.